# Как экранировать SQL запрос, чтобы избежать SQL injections?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, параметры

Каким образом можно экранировать SQL запрос, чтобы избежать *SQL injection*?

```
def getStackArea(screen_area):
    db = postgresql.open(db_conf.connectionString())
    data = db.query("select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = " + screen_area + " and active = 1")
    return data[0]['stack_area']
```

Comment: Не надо ничего экранировать. Надо применять запросы с параметрами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
cur = conn.cursor()
q = "select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = ? and active = ?"

cur.execute(sql, (screen_area,1))
row = cur.fetchone()
stack_area = row[0]
```

или используя `py-postgresql`:

```
q = "select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = $1 and active = $2"
row = db.query.first(sql, (screen_area,1))
...
```

PS похоже параметризация в `py-postgresql` реализована не в [полном объеме, как это описано в PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

Comment: пример с py-postgresql не  хочет работать.

Comment: К сожалению не могу проверить ответ на практике. А что за ошибка?

Comment: syntax error at or near "and" `select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = ? and active = ?`

Comment: заменил ? на $1, $2 - все работает