# Как правильно подставлять значения из переменных / списков / словарей в SQL запрос?

Tags: python, sql, параметры, передача-параметров, python-faq

Все чаще стали появляться вопросы о том, как правильно подставить в SQL запрос значения из переменных и об ошибках, связанных с неправильной подстановкой значений.

Вот несколько примеров таких вопросов:

- [Почему при вставке в таблицу передаваемые значения воспринимаются как названия столбцов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1201294/211923)
- [Как устранить ошибку "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ..."?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374647/211923)
- [Как экранировать SQL запрос, чтобы избежать SQL injections?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/908754/211923)
- [Как передавать параметр типа string в SQL запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374066/211923)
- [Как правильно заменить местозаполнители в запросе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1329683/211923)
- [SQL запрос с несколькими условиями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1377901/211923)

Поэтому я решил создать новый обобщённый вопрос и более-менее канонический ответ для того, чтобы ссылаться на него в будущем. Данный ответ планируется расширять новыми подробностями и примерами.

Comment: Как вовремя этот вопрос-ответ появился, за пару дней уже двоих сюда задупликатил :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, ага, что-то часто стали эти вопросы возникать)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать SQL запросы с использованием параметров:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ?", [123])
# parameter placeholder ------------------------> ^
# список/кортеж со значениями параметров -----------> ^^^^^
```

Какие преимущества приносит использование параметров?

- **Защита от [SQL Injections](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).** Смотрите пример `SQL Injection`внизу.
- **правильное квотирование литералов** в зависимости от их типа ([пример со строками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201295/211923), [пример с датами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1169742/211923)).
- **Оптимизация** - сокращение времени работы SQL запроса. Благодаря использованию параметров следующие шаги **не** выполняются при повторном запуске (В зависимости от типа базы данных и от их настроек либо все либо некоторые из данных шагов будут пропущены при повторном выполнении):

  - проверка синтаксиса SQL запроса
  - проверка прав доступа к объектам БД
  - построение плана выполнения SQL запроса
- **Защита от переполнения/вытеснения кеша SQL запросов**. Например "безобидный" запрос `qry = f"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE id = {user_id}"`, который часто выполняется в нагруженной системе с различными значениями `user_id` может вытеснить из кеша запросов полезные запросы. Если использовать `qry = f"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE id = ?"` - в кеше запросов сохранится только один запрос, т.к. его `checksum` не изменяется вне зависимости от значения параметра.

[Пример использования параметров в SQL запросе](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table lang (name, first_appeared)")

# This is the qmark style:
cur.execute("insert into lang values (?, ?)", ("C", 1972))

# The qmark style used with executemany():
lang_list = [
    ("Fortran", 1957),
    ("Python", 1991),
    ("Go", 2009),
]
cur.executemany("insert into lang values (?, ?)", lang_list)

# And this is the named style:
cur.execute("select * from lang where first_appeared=:year", {"year": 1972})
print(cur.fetchall())

con.close()
```

При таком подходе можно использовать `cursor.executemany()` - это значительно быстрее и эффективнее по сравнению с вставкой в цикле по одной строке.

Стоит упомянуть о том, что параметризировать можно только значения, но не наименования объектов БД (таблиц, столбцов, индексов, `constraints`, etc.). Для подстановки наименований БД придется использовать форматирование строк или же "хардкодировать" их.

Пример:

```
table_name = "my_table"
column_name = "id"
qry = f"SELECT max({column_name}) as max_val FROM {table_name}"
cursor.execute(qry)
```

В этом запросе невозможно параметризировать имя таблицы или имя столбца - их можно подставить при помощи форматирования строк.

К сожалению в Python нет единого стандарта стиля параметров (`paramstyle`) БД - выбор `paramstyle` зависит от реализации драйвера БД. В [PEP-0249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) указаны все возможные виды `paramstyle`:

| paramstyle | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| qmark | Question mark style, e.g. ...WHERE name = **?** |
| numeric | Numeric, positional style, e.g. ...WHERE name = **:1** |
| named | Named style, e.g. ...WHERE name = **:name** |
| format | ANSI C printf format codes, e.g. ...WHERE name = **%s** |
| pyformat | Python extended format codes, e.g. ...WHERE name = **%(name)s** |

Вот список поддерживаемых `paramstyle` для наиболее популярных драйверов БД в Python:

| DB driver | paramstyle |
| --- | --- |
| sqlite3 | qmark (`?`), numeric (`:1`) |
| cx_Oracle | named (`:name`), numeric (`:1`) |
| pymysql | format (`%s`) |
| mysql.connector | format (`%s`), pyformat (`%(name)s`) |
| psycopg2 | format (`%s`), pyformat (`%(name)s`) |
| pymssql | format (`%s`), pyformat (`%(name)s`) |
| PyODBC | qmark (`?`) |

---

> [Как динамически сформировать запрос с заранее неизвестным количеством
> параметров (значения параметров заданы в виде списка)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1375438/211923)

> Например как передать параметры в следующий запрос с использованием `named`
> "paramstyle":

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE data in (:param_name1, :param_name2, ...)
```

Можно динамически сформировать запрос и словарь с параметрами:

```
values = ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']
param_names = [f"p{i}" for i in range(len(values))]
in_str = ", ".join(":" + p for p in param_names))
params = dict(zip(param_names, values))
qry = f"""SELECT * FROM table WHERE data in ({in_str})"""
cursor.execute(qry, params)
```

получим такие запрос и параметры:

```
In [82]: qry
Out[82]: 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE data in (:p0, :p1, :p2)'

In [83]: params
Out[83]: {'p0': 'val_1', 'p1': 'val_2', 'p2': 'val_3'}
```

---

Пример `SQL Injection` (**никогда так не делайте - это опасно**):

```
id_ = input("Введите ID клиента: ")
cur.execute(f"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE id = {id_}")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

"Злобный хакер" может ввести следующее значение "id": `123 UNION ALL SELECT username, password FROM secure_logins`

В итоге в базе данных выполнится следующий запрос:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE id = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT username, password FROM secure_logins
```

вместо того, чтобы вывести только имя и фамилию введенного клиента - программа выведет еще и **все** логины и пароли на экран.

Как сделать правильно (безопасно):

```
id_ = int(input("Введите ID клиента: "))
cur.execute(f"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE id = ?", [id_])
```

В таком варианте сервер БД вернет сообщение об ошибке на попытку хакерской атаки.