# Передача списка параметров в SQL запрос python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Пример запроса:

```
params = {'par': 'val'}
sql = """SELECT data FROM table
         WHERE data = :par"""
ret = pd.read_sql(sql, params=params, con=ora_conn)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сформировать аналогичный запрос, но со списком значений параметра, вроде того:

```
values = ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']
values = str(values)[1:-1]
params = {'par': values}
sql = """SELECT data FROM table
         WHERE data in (:par)"""
ret = pd.read_sql(sql, params=params, con=ora_conn)
```

Сейчас я делаю так:

```
values = ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']
values = str(values)[1:-1]
sql = """SELECT data FROM table
         WHERE data in """ + """(""" + values + """)"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать динамически:

```
param_names = [f"p{i}" for i in range(len(values))]

in_str = ", ".join(":" + p for p in param_names))

params = dict(zip(param_names, values))

sql = f"""SELECT data FROM table
         WHERE data in ({in_str})"""
```

результат:

```
In [77]: in_str
Out[77]: ':p0, :p1, :p2'

In [78]: params
Out[78]: {'p0': 'val_1', 'p1': 'val_2', 'p2': 'val_3'}

In [79]: print(sql)
SELECT data FROM table
         WHERE data in (:p0, :p1, :p2)
```

Comment: Супер, то что нужно!!! Огромное спасибо!)))

Comment: Только, params = {key[1:]: value for key, value in zip(param_names, values)}

Comment: @onetwoonexu, спасибо! Исправил )