# Как вставить большую JSON строку в БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, mariadb, mysqlconnector

Помогите вставить большую JSON строку в mariadb10.4. И какой лучше использовать тип данных в таблице?

````
{
    "content": "You can~~not~~ do `this`.```py\nAnd this.\nprint('Hi')```\n*italics* or _italics_     __*underline italics*__\n**bold**     __**underline bold**__\n***bold italics***  __***underline bold italics***__\n__underline__     ~~Strikethrough~~",
    "embed": {
        "title": "Hello ~~people~~ world :wave:",
        "description": "You can use [links](https://discord.com) or emojis :smile: \n```\nAnd also code blocks\n```",
        "color": 4321431,
        "timestamp": "2022-01-28T20:30:15.484Z",
        "url": "https://discord.com",
        "author": {
            "name": "Author name",
            "url": "https://discord.com",
            "icon_url": "https://unsplash.it/100"
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "https://unsplash.it/200"
        },
        "image": {
            "url": "https://unsplash.it/380/200"
        },
        "footer": {
            "text": "Footer text",
            "icon_url": "https://unsplash.it/100"
        },
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Field 1, *lorem* **ipsum**, ~~dolor~~",
                "value": "Field value"
            },
            {
                "name": "Field 2",
                "value": "You can use custom emojis <:Kekwlaugh:722088222766923847>. <:GangstaBlob:742256196295065661>",
                "inline": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Inline field",
                "value": "Fields can be inline",
                "inline": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Inline field",
                "value": "*Lorem ipsum*",
                "inline": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Inline field",
                "value": "value",
                "inline": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Another field",
                "value": "> Nope, didn't forget about this",
                "inline": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
````

Comment: А в чем проблема? Если размер JSON строки не превышает 21.844 байта (для utf8) то особой разницы нет. Вставляйте также как если бы вы вставляли маленькую строку

Comment: Использую MySQL-connector, попробуйте вставить эту строку, лично у меня 1064 error. Как быть со специальными символами?

Comment: @RAINGM кодировка какая выставлена в СУБД?

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Покажите в вопросе как вы вставляете строку и приведите полный текст ошибки - MariaDB обычно даёт подсказку о месте с ошибкой

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если [правильно использовать параметризированные запросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374687/211923) - все должно отработать без проблем:

```
qry = """
create table test(
   id int not null auto_increment
  ,json varchar(65000) collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
  ,primary key(id)
)
"""
cursor.execute(qry)

json_str = """<your_JSON_string>"""
qry = """insert into test(json) values(%s)"""
cursor.execute(qry, [json_str])
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку `mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1366 (22007): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8B",...'`

Comment: @RAINGM, я не смог воспроизвести ошибку с JSON строкой из вопроса

Comment: У меня тип данных `LONGTEXT`, в mariadb это эквивалент `JSON`