# Ошибка pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Tags: python, sql-server, flask

Из 7-8 попыток запроса, 1-2 раза выдает ошибку `pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')`
Код в котором выполняются запросы:

```
    def GetIdleData(self, request, tpaIndex):
    idleData = []
    cursor = connections['DB_Name'].execute(f''' SELECT [Idle].[Oid],[RepairObject],[Наименование],[IdleType],[CreateDate],[StartDate],
                                                            [EndDate],[Cause],[Note],[Creator],[PressForm],[Ordinance]
                                                    FROM [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name] AS [Idle],[DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name] AS [OBR]
                                                    WHERE [Idle].[Oid] = '{tpaIndex}' AND [Idle].[RepairObject] = [OBR].[Oid] ''')
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        idleData.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        
    defectList = self.GetDefectList()
    malfunctionDescription = self.GetMalfunctionDescription()
    takenMeasures = self.GetTakenMeasures()
                
    return idleData, defectList, malfunctionDescription, takenMeasures

def GetDefectList(self):
    defectList = []
    cursor = connections['DB_Name'].execute(f''' SELECT [Oid],[Код]
                                                    FROM [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name] ''')
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        defectList.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    
    return defectList

def GetMalfunctionDescription(self):
    malfunctionDescription = []
    cursor = connections['DB_Name'].execute(f''' SELECT [Oid],[Код]
                                                    FROM [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]''')
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        malfunctionDescription.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

    return malfunctionDescription

def GetTakenMeasures(self):
    takenMeasures = []
    cursor = connections['DB_Name'].execute(f''' SELECT [Oid],[Код],[Наименование],[СтатусОбъекта]
                                                    FROM [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]
                                                    WHERE [GCRecord] IS NULL
                                                    AND [СтатусОбъекта] = '1'
                                                    ORDER BY [Наименование] ''')
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        takenMeasures.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        
    return takenMeasures
```

Comment: Почитайте для начала как правильно передавать параметры в запрос. Может этого будет достаточно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80

Comment: @CrazyElf передача параметров без форматирования строки, никаких результатов не дала

Comment: Ладно, значит не в этом дело. А у самого ODBC нет какого-нибудь лога, может там посмотреть?

Comment: @CrazyElf к сожалению, нет

Comment: @CrazyElf Иногда выдает такую ошибку: `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Недопустимое состояние курсора (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')`
Если сделать повторно запрос, обрабатывается без ошибки