# Python, oracle как создать условие where

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Здравствуйте пытаюсь изучать Python методом проб и ошибок без курсов и т.п,
возникла проблем с условием.
Есть подключение к БД oracle через cx_oracle где два столбца со значениями код товара(skucode) и наименование товара(name)
Я хочу чтобы у меня при запуске файла был выбор значений по столбцу skucode через условие, т.е. при введении 000w000 он выдавала этот код и его наименование
Пробовал numpy но что то не выходит из за отсутствия познаний, перерыл кучу форумов но понять не смог
вот код

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT skucode, name FROM sku where skucode like '%w%'""")
res=cursor.fetchall()
for row in res:
    skucode = row [0]
    name = row[1]
print("Код товара: "+ skucode + " Наименование товара " + name)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Так что в итоге, `where skucode like '%w%'` не работает? Должно работать. А если напрямую к БД обратиться, без питона, такой селект работает?

Comment: такой select работает

Comment: А в питоне не работает? Или в чём проблема собственно? Непонятно. Или вы без БД хотите такой поиск делать?

Comment: проблема в том что мне нужно получить одну запись по условию, и чтобы это не было в selecte

Comment: я хочу выше указанное подключение, подключить к боту telegram, чтобы пользователь при вводе значения 200w222 получал сообщение Код товара 200w222 Наименование товара Таракан шестилапый.

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то фактически мне нужно чтобы столбец skucode был переменной в python для вывода значения наименования

Comment: Вот отсюда вопрос как настроить эту переменную skucode из бд oracle в python

Comment: для начала сделайте print(res) что бы понять что именно вам вернули, а потом уже от этого и пляшите

Comment: print(res) мне выдает список товаров

Comment: А зачем вы используете цикл если вам нужна всего одна запись ? достаточно просто `print("Код товара: "+ res[0][0] + " Наименование товара " + res[0][1])` а вообще вместо fetchall наверняка можно использовать просто fetch, что бы он вам вернул только первую строку. Нет смысла тянуть с сервера все записи если используется только одна

Comment: @Mike fetchall и fetch для меня еще такие поверхностные понятия но все равно спасибо за пояснения, суть в чем я создал переменную sku, теперь у меня возник вопрос каким образом затащить эту переменную в запрос cursor.execute("""SELECT skucode, name FROM sku where skucode = переменная")

Comment: посмотрите документацию на ваш модуль работы с базой данных, там наверняка есть примеры. модули для разных БД используют разный синтаксис

Comment: @Миахил Вы ссылку посмотрели, которую я там выше приводил? Это не то, что нужно?

Comment: @CrazyElf - спасибо за ссылки, я решил вопрос, теперь куча других но это чуть позже, то что мне надо было сделал, теперь упорядочиваю написания запроса для введения input()

Comment: Если это то, что нужно, то я закрою этот вопрос как дубликат того более общего вопроса

Comment: @CrazyElf - хорошо можно закрывать, еще раз всем спасибо, мне так нравиться получать удовольствие от того когда все получается

Answer (score 1):

```
res=("SELECT skucode, name FROM sku where skucode = :skus")
print("Введите код товара")
cursor.execute((res),{'skus':input()})
res=cursor.fetchall()
for row in res:
    skucode = row[0]
    name = row[1]
print("Код товара " + skucode + " Наименование товара " + name)
conn.close()
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Не понятно зачем нужно было запрос в отдельную переменную было выносить.