# Временный бонус discord.py /timely

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Я хотел бы сделать добавление случайного числа, по стандарту выдается 100, но как сделать, чтобы вместо 100 было к примеру 122, 152, 170 (предел 200)?

Вот код:

````
@commands.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 18000, commands.BucketType.user)
async def timely(self, ctx):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash +100 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
    db.commit()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"**Временная награда пользователя\n — {ctx.author}**",
        description = f"", color = 0x2f3136
    )
    embed.add_field(name="<:dot:999002978486861914>Баланс:", value=f'``` {cursor.execute("SELECT cash from users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} ```', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="<:dot:999002978486861914>Начислено:", value=f'``` 100 ```', inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.author.avatar.url}")
    embed.set_footer(text="Бонус можно получить один раз в 12 часов")
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

random_amount = random.randint(100, 200)

cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ? WHERE id = ?", (random_amount, ctx.author.id))
```

Comment: Лучше не использовать форматирование для подстановки значений в sql запрос: [Как правильно подставлять значения из переменных / списков / словарей в SQL запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374687/1365)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду подобное этому, просто не совсем разобрался

`sql = ("INSERT INTO levels(guild_id, user_id, exp, lvl) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)")                                               
 val = (message.author.guild.id, message.author.id, 2, 0)
  cursor.execute(sql, val)`

Comment: Я имею в виду `cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ? WHERE id = ?", (random_amount, ctx.author.id))`

Comment: Хорошо, буду пользоваться этим, спасибо за совет