# Как передать переменные в f-строки соседнего скрипта?

Tags: python, sql, f-strings

Мой проект состоит из нескольких скриптов:

1. main.py

   ```
   from dbconnect import execute_from_db  
   if __name__ == '__main__':  
       x = '2022-05-25'     
       y = '2022-06-01'   
       execute_data = execute_from_db()
   ```
2. dbconnect.py Для подключения к БД, получения результатов запросов из sql_code.py

   ```
   import sql_code  
   def execute_from_db():  
       con = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=db_user, password=db_password, database=database)  
       with con:  
           cur = con.cursor()  
           cur.execute(sql_code.all) 
       return cur.fetchall()
   ```
3. sql_code.py Содержит запросы к БД в виде f-строк

   ```
   all = "SELECT * " \
         "FROM jiraissue ji " \
         f"WHERE ji.created > '{x}' " \
         f"AND ji.created < '{y}') "
   ```

Как-то возможно передать переменные из main.py в f-строки sql_code.py или я составил некорректную структуру проекта? Как можно лучше организовать данный функционал(чтобы запросы хранились отдельно от кода подключения к БД и динамически менялись в зависимости от введенных в main.py параметров)?

Comment: Самый простой способ, который приходит на ум завернуть f-строку all в какую-нибудь функцию с аргументами x, y. Но является ли это единственным решением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Используйте параметры функции для передачи x, y в функцию `execute_from_db`
2. Внутри функции `execute_from_db` подставляйте параметры средствами SQL библиотеки. Лучше сверяться с документацией, т.к. синтаксис может различаться. Для pymysql смотрите пример здесь: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

   ***Не используйте*** f-строки и другие способы форматирования для подстановки параметров SQL запросов - это делает ваш код потенциально подверженным SQL инъекциям.

   Предположим, даты у вас берутся из http запроса. Злоумышленник может выполнить свой запрос, подставив вместо даты кусок SQL кода, который, например, удалит у вас базе парочку "ненужных" таблиц.

   К прочтению: [Как правильно подставлять значения из переменных / списков / словарей в SQL запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374687/1365)
3. Если очень хочется (не для SQL запросов) - используйте метод `format`.

   Подставлять в f-строку так как вы хотите не получится - f-строка у вас получает свое фактическое значение в момент импорта вашего модуля (в момент "выполнения" f-строки). Можно обернуть f-строку в функцию, но проще использовать более "старое" средство форматирования строк - метод `format`.

```
from dbconnect import execute_from_db  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    x = '2022-05-25'     
    y = '2022-06-01'   
    execute_data = execute_from_db(x, y)
```

```
import sql_code  
def execute_from_db(x, y):  
    con = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=db_user, password=db_password, database=database)  
    with con:  
        cur = con.cursor()  
        cur.execute(sql_code.all, (x, y)) 
    return cur.fetchall()
```

```
all = "SELECT * " \
        "FROM jiraissue ji " \
        "WHERE ji.created > %s " \
        "AND ji.created < %s "
```

---

Подстановка значений в строку с помощью метода `format`:

```
import some_strings

name = input("Введите ваше имя:")
print(some_strings.greeting.format(name=name))
```

`some_strings.py`:

```
greeting = "Привет, {name}!"  # Обычная строка (не f-строка)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Нужно было всего-то прочитать описание функции execute :facepalm