# ошибка 'NoneType' object is not iterable при использовании переменных в sql запросе python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql

пользователь вводит данные:

```
store = input('')
pos = input('')
receipt = input('')
date = input('')
```

эти данные в виде переменных добавляю в select:

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         """select........AND zsu.SAP_id = """ + str(store) + """ AND torh.pos = """ + str(pos) + """ AND torh.global_number = """ + str(receipt) + """ AND date(torh.date)= """ + str(date)cursor.execute(select_all_rows)
        rows = cursor.fetchone()  
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
        #print("#" * 20)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

и получаю ошибку:`'NoneType' object is not iterable`
Но, если в коде Select вместо переменных указать конкретные значение,которые вводит пользователь, то все работает без ошибок!
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема?

Comment: А как вы указываете конкретные значения переменных?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно подставлять значения из переменных / списков / словарей в SQL запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80)

Answer (score 0):

Если в select прописать:
`... And zsu.sap_id=123 And torh.pos=456 And torh.global_number=789 And date(torh.date)='2022-10-17'`
В этом случае все работает.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите