# Ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Возникла проблема при создании таблицы в SQLite3 напрямую через код

Сам код:

```py
chatid = message.chat.id

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?(
id INT,
admins INT,
nick TEXT,
warns INT,
vip INT), (chatid,)
""")
db.commit()
await message.answer("Табличка создана")
```

При попытке все это выполнить, вылезает трейсбэк:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  

File "C:\Users\Глеб\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Глеб\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Глеб\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Глеб\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Глеб\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\!python\проекты\bot_chat\main.py", line 64, in botstart
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?(
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Comment: никак нельзя назвать таблицу содержимым переменной? Это второе, что пришло на ум. Первое было поставить перед запросом f и с помощью фигурных скобок "впилить" переменную, но это тоже провалилось

Comment: Таблицу нельзя назвать используя "?". Либо попробуйте `[?]`.

Comment: А Вы где-то передаете название таблицы в `execute` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

создавайте таблицу вот так, если вам надо передать параметр в строку `execute`

```py
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(
id INT,
admins INT,
nick TEXT,
warns INT,
vip INT)
""" % (str(chatid)),)
```

Comment: А не лучше кортеж передавать с данными после строки запроса? Есть риск SQL инъекции

Comment: @Ovsenka В том то и дело, что подставлять названия таблиц и колонок нельзя нормальным образом, только вот так. Безопасный механизм есть только подстановки значений.

Comment: Ах, да, только форматированием строки :) т.е без параметризация. Не знал. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80) кстати был вопрос как правильно подставлять