# За что отвечает буква f в строчке?

Tags: python, текст, графика, клавиатура

в чем разница между geometry('400x500') и geometry(f'400x500')
За что отвечает буква f в строчке ?

Comment: Ни в чём, потому что в этой f-строке нет никаких подстановок переменных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае `geometry('400x500')` и `geometry(f'400x500')` разницы нет, но `f` - это строковый литерал, условно - способ форматирования строки. Например, ты можешь вывести следующее значение таким образом:

```
i = range(10)
for r in i:
    print("Значение: ", r)
#"Значение:  0"
#"Значение:  1"
#"Значение:  2"
#"Значение:  3"
#"Значение:  4"
#"Значение:  5"
#"Значение:  6"
#"Значение:  7"
#"Значение:  8"
#"Значение:  9"
```

Либо же более красивое форматирование:

```
i = range(10)
for r in i:
    print(f"Значение: {r}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Это называется *форматирование* строк. Если перед строкой стоит *f*, то в самой строке, то что находится в фигурных скобках рассматривается как переменная, значение которой и будет вставлено в строку:

```
name = 'Ivan'
print(f'Hello, {name}!')
```

В Вашем конкретном случае необходимость в f-строке может быть выражена так:

```
str_1 = "size 500x500"

size = 500
str_2 = f"size {size}x{size}"

print(str_1)
print(str_2)
```

PS

Вообще, этот способ форматирования возможен в питоне с версии 3.6.
До этого использовался менее синтаксически удобный:

```
name = 'Ivan'
print('Hey {name}!'.format(name=name))
```

Но смысл абсолютно тот же

Comment: Хочу отметить, что "старые" способы форматирования строк до сих используются , например, в sql запросах, по соображениям безопасности

Comment: @Dmitry как раз из соображений безопасности обычное форматирование строк (ни через f-строки, ни через format, ни через %) в sql запросах лучше не использовать.

Comment: @insolor мне на ум сразу пришла библиотека  для postgresa, я помню, что там нельзя применять ф строку. Все остальное допустимо

Comment: @Dmitry [Как правильно подставлять значения из переменных / списков / словарей в SQL запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374687/1365)

Comment: @Dmitry с точки зрения безопасности (небезопасности) нет разницы между f-строками, format и %