# Код завершается, пропуская цикл for

Tags: python, sqlite3

Пропускается `for` и завершается код, не понимаю в чем проблема.

#### Код:

```py
import random
import sqlite3


def randomizer():
    cards = ['`mbc20017`', '`25bmw320d`', '`26bmwx3`']
    get_card = random.choice(cards)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM user_regular_card WHERE user_id={}'.format(get_card, '942912999'))
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

    for gtc in users:
        if gtc[0] == 0:
            print(gtc[0] + '=' + gtc[0])
        elif gtc[0] == 1:
            print('Перезапускаю..')

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


randomizer()
```

```py
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — а почему вы решили, что `for` не должен пропускаться? В `users` есть хотя бы что-нибудь?

Comment: В `users` есть выведенные данные, через `print(gtc[0])` проверял

Comment: А `print(repr(gtc[0]))`?

Comment: значения выводятся

Comment: Ну, может быть, не равно ни 0, ни 1.

Comment: если добавить `else: print(gtc[0])`, то выводится либо `0`, либо `1`. Также и в бд есть значение либо `0`, либо `1`, другого к счастью не дано в бд

Comment: `print(type(gtc[0]))`

Comment: `<class 'str'>` - выводит это

Comment: Ну вот, строки никогда не бывают равны числам

Comment: не очень понятно

Comment: понял свою ошибку, указывал неверный тип данных в бд

Comment: И вот это почитайте. Не используйте подстановку параметров через форматирование https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80

Comment: Можно просто сравнивать не `gtc[0] == 0`, а `gtc[0] == '0'`. И в elif'е соответственно.

Comment: @wchistow, напишите это в ответ

Comment: @panickx, написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения проблемы - сравнивать не с числами, а со строками:

```py
...

def randomizer():
    ...

    for gtc in users:
        if gtc[0] == '0':
        #            ^ ^
            print(gtc[0] + '=' + gtc[0])
        elif gtc[0] == '1':
        #              ^ ^
            print('Перезапускаю..')

...
```