# Когда вызываю reglogin() и выбираю 1(Регистрация) вписываю логин и пароль выбивает ошибку

Tags: python, sqlite3

```
import sqlite3

File = open('db-ID.txt')
id = File.read()
File.close()

def reglogin():
    print("1 - Reg\n2 - Login")
    choice = int(input("Please, choice(1 or 2): "))
    if choice == 1:
        Login = input("Login - ")
        Password = input("Password - ")
        with sqlite3.connect("db/moneydb.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            query = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accaunt(mID INTAGER, mlogin TEXT, mpassword TEXT, mmoney TEXT) """
            cursor.execute(query)
            query2 = " INSERT INTO accaunt (mID, mlogin, mpassword, mmoney) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )", [id, Login, Password, '0']
            cursor.execute(query2)
            #query3 = """ SELECT ID FROM accaunt WHERE mlogin = """
            #cursor.execute(query3)
            db.commit()
    elif choice == 2:
        ...
    else:
        reglogin()

reglogin()
File = open('db-ID.txt', "w")
File.write(id+1)
File.close()
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FILE", line 27, in 
reglogin()
File "FILE", line 18, in reglogin
cursor.execute(query2)
TypeError: execute() argument 1 must be str, not tuple

Comment: `f""" INSERT INTO accaunt (mID, mlogin, mpassword, mmoney) VALUES ( {id}, {Login}, {Password}, '0')"""` - в этой строке у вас логин и пароль подставляются в sql запрос без кавычек. См. [Как правильно подставлять значения из переменных / списков / словарей в SQL запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/Как-правильно-подставлять-значения-из-переменных-списков-словарей-в-sql-запр)

Comment: А тут вообще не полный запрос, после = что-то должно идти: `query3 = """ SELECT ID FROM accaunt WHERE mlogin = """`

Comment: У меня была ошибка в бд, у меня била таблица акаунтов ч заменил значение а таблица не создалась