# SQLite Строка во фразе WHERE предложения SELECT

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть очень простая БД *nmon*, состоящая всего из двух таблиц:

```
$ sqlite3 nmon.db
sqlite> .tables
monument  type_mom
```

Во второй таблице *type_mom* всего одна запись:

```
sqlite> select * from type_mom;
1|nature
```

Мне нужно выполнить поиск по строковой колонке *name* во второй таблице, что бы получить значение из первой колонки - *id* этой записи.

В python программе делаю это так:

```
tt = 'nature'
ex_string = f"select id from type_mom where name='{tt}'"
print(ex_string)
con.execute(ex_string)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

Но строка в таблице не находится! На печать выдаётся:

```
select id from type_mom where name='nature'
None
```

Самое загадочное в том, что если я просто сделаю копипаст строки *select id from type_mom where name='nature'* в консольную утилиту, то всё отрабатывает нормально:

```
sqlite> select id from type_mom where name='nature';
1
```

Почему один и тот же оператор *select* нормально работает в консоли и не работает в программе на python ?

Comment: Нормальную подстановку параметра в запрос попробуйте всё-таки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1374688/260769  И ещё попробуйте через питон `select` без `where`. Вдруг вы не ту базу запрашиваете, например. Нужно всё проверять )  А так то может быть через питон другие кавычки нужны, чем через консоль или ещё какая-то тонкость, подстановка параметров часть таких вопросов снимает.

Comment: @CrazyElf *попробуйте через питон select без where.* Попробовал. Разницы нет. *select id from type_mom
None*

Comment: @CrazyElf *Вдруг вы не ту базу запрашиваете, например.* Но тогда абсолютно непонятно, как я на строчку выше выполнил оператор *con.execute('insert into type_mom (name) values (?)', (tt,))* и этот оператор отработал нормально - вставил эту строку в таблицу.

Comment: что такое `cursor` и как эта переменная связана с `con`?

Comment: А вы закоммитить, кстати, не забыли то, что вставили? )  Может транзакция откатилась и в базе просто ничего нет ))

Comment: @CrazyElf *может быть через питон другие кавычки нужны* - проверил, действительно, если апострофы заменить на двойные кавычки, то ругается на синтаксис. Но у меня - правильно.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA   *что такое cursor и как эта переменная связана с con? – con = sl.connect('nmon.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()*

Comment: @Sergey А вот по той ссылке, что я выше дал, и `execute` и `fetch` делаются через курсор. У вас какая-то путаница/мешанина в плане курсора и коннекшена. Может в этом и проблема? Если всё сделать в одном курсоре, наверняка сработает. И приз уходит Roman-у.

Comment: @CrazyElf *А вы закоммитить, кстати, не забыли то, что вставили? )* - Но ведь в консоли я ВИЖУ эту строку! Значит она там есть...

Comment: conn.execute создает новый курсор, старый становится недействительным

Comment: @CrazyElf *делаются через курсор*  Точно !!! Проглядел... Оформите, как ответ - я галочку Вам поставлю :-)

Comment: @Sergey Я лучше закрою дубликатом на ту ссылку. Она как обычно решает все проблемы, хотя сразу бывает и непонятно, что именно нарушено из рекомендаций в данном случае )

Answer (score 1):

```
ex_string = f"select id from type_mom where name='{tt}'"
con.execute(ex_string)
```

Своим не правильным запросом, вы получает объект Cusor, теперь из этого экземпляра нужно взять кортеж.

попробуйте так :

```
print(con.execute("select id from type_mom where name=?",(tt,)).fetchone())
```

Comment: 1) Почему *НЕправильный* ? 2) Я делаю *row = cursor.fetchone()*.

Comment: 1. НЕправильный, потому что небезопасный ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1374688/260769, 2. у нового, совсем другого объекта