Спасёт ли этот фильтр от sql инъекции
у меня есть телеграмм бот на aiogram и я хочу защитить его от sql инъекции, и  вот теперь думаю, поможет ли этот фильтр от инъекции.
При этом для работы с бд я использую sqlalchemy
def is_valid_text(text):
    # Регулярное выражение для поиска запрещенных символов
    pattern = r"[\/\\\*\-=\+\[\]\{\};%~:'\"|]|select|update|execute|or"
    return not re.search(pattern, text)


Есть похожий запрос: How do PyMySQL prevent user from sql injection attack?

Лучший способ защититься от инъекций - это правильно обращаться к БД. Не подставлять самому параметры интерполяцией или конкатенацией строк, а использовать средства подстановки параметров в запрос самой библиотеки работы с БД.

Вот это читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80/1374688#1374688

Есть ещё одна интересная статья по этой теме: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/11/preventing-sql-injections/

А этот фильтр не поможет?

user = await session.scalar(select(User).where(User.tg_id == tg_id))
if user:
    # Если пользователь существует, обновляем его данные
    await session.execute(
        update(User).where(User.id == user.id).values(
            name=data.get("name"),
            surname=data.get("surname"),
            patronymic=data.get("patronymic"),
            department=data.get("department"),
            office=data.get("office")
        )
    )

    )
    session.add(new_user)

await session.commit()


Независимо от того поможет или нет, этот фильтр — глупость

А если вы используете sqlalchemy — в нём же уже встроенная защита от sql-инъекций, так что переизобретая уже изобретённую штуку — вы делаете дважды глупость

А почему, он же отсекает те символы, которые могут использоваться для sql инъекции

А ещё он отсекает символы, которые могут использоваться в нормальном разговоре

Вы вот не задумывались, почему, когда вы создавали вопрос, сайт Stack Overflow не отклонил ваш код с этими символами? Сайту ведь тоже нужно защищаться от sql-инъекций в вопросах, но ваши символы он почему-то не запретил, что-то здесь не так, наверное?

Ааа, я всё понял, спасибо что подсказали мне

Получается, что в sqlalchemy уже есть защита от этого

Не размещайте код в комментариях, он тут не читабелен. Хотите добавить код - добавляйте его в вопрос, вы можете его редактировать. А в целом предлагаю всё-таки пройти по моей ссылке, там всё написано и про инъекции и как правильно передавать параметры.

А еще помимо update select существуют такие команды как DROP, TRUNCATE, DELETE, ALTER - ими можно таких дел натворить...
